# DB Will not open from a link using file:/// in Chrome

Tags: html, file-uri

Link code in question:

```
<a href="file:///G:\Fileshare\General\PO_Database\PO.mdb">Purchase Order Database</a>
```

Opens just fine in IE... why not in FF or Chrome? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This issue is caused by default security settings in Chrome and Firefox.**

In order to have Chrome automatically open a *.mdb file after being downloaded, perform the following steps:

1) First time, tell the browser that you want to keep the file

[image: Tell Chrome to keep file type]

2) Tell the browser that you want to open the file automatically from now on

[image: tell Chrome to auto-open file type]

3) After step #2, you will notice in your Chrome settings a new button to "Clear auto-opening settings"

[image: Clear auto-opening settings button in Chrome]

4) Associate the file extension with Microsoft Access program

[image: associate file extension with program]

Comment: +1 !! wow I cannot +2,3,4 it :) :).. What a pictured answer.. :)

Comment: I see how it works, so I'll mark it answered. But, I asked the wrong questions... as this method still seems to save a copy of the file and open that. This being our PO database, I need to open that file over the network, not a copy of it... if I am understanding correctly that is. Will have to ask a more appropriate question for that... thanks for this answer though, hopefully it helps someone else out :)